# Run pgTAP with Perl prove instead of pg_prove

Tags: perl, postgresql, tap

I have a test-suit as usual for Perl projects, containing a `lib` and a `t` directory. The tests in `t` are structured through subdirectories. So I run them using:

```
prove -Ilib -r t/
```

So far nothing special, and afaik quite a standard way of testing in Perl.

Since it is the assumption, that this is the standard way of testing, I'd like to make sure that the following applies:

*"If you run `prove -r` on `t`, you have tested everything that is there to test".*

This is very important, since otherwise you can never be sure that you really called all the tests and the stuff is fine. Somebody calling the above would then maybe - not knowing so - just call a part of the available tests, leaving some behind. Quite annoying... tests that are not run, are of no help. It should be as easy and predictive as possible for developers to call all the tests! It is a bad thing when you have to look up how to run the rest of the test-suit. You might not know about it, or might not do it anyway.

So here comes my problem: I have to integrate some Tests using [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/) which kindly provides the tool `pg_prove`. Now I have to make two commandos to do the testing. Additionally to running `prove -Ilib -r` I also have to run something like e.g. `pg_prove -S schema=customerX -U dbuser -d dbname t/pgTAP/*.sql`. The problem is not that big if you call the tests automatically from `cron` or what ever. But it really decreases the chance that we *lazy* developers run all test tests during our busy days.

So I wonder what would be the best approach to implement the tests in such a way that `prove` will also include those tests. Is it, that I have to create some `.t`-files which wrap the whole thing (and how?)? Are there any tricks I can do with the whole `Harness` stuff on CPAN? Would a simple `test_all.sh` in the root-dir, including both commandos, do the best job, even if it breaks the assumptions I made above?

**So my question in short is:** Can I run all tests, including pgTAP with `prove`? If not, is there a best practice for solving my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, `pg_prove` just passes everything off to `prove`. Assuming your pgTAP tests end in `.sql`, you can run all your tests like this:

```
prove -lr --ext .sql --ext .t \
--source pgTAP \
--pgtap-option dbname=dbname \
--pgtap-option username=dbuser \
--pgtap-option suffix=.pg \
--pgtap-option set=schema=customerX
```

If you use Module::Build, you can also have `./Build test` run all the tests, too, as I've done [for circle](https://github.com/theory/circle/blob/master/Build.PL).
See [the TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/TAP%3a%3aParser%3a%3aSourceHandler%3a%3apgTAP) for details.

Comment: Any time. You can also post questions to the [pgTAP mail list](http://pgfoundry.org/mail/?group_id=1000389).

Comment: I had to remove the `--pgtap-option suffix=.pg` part, but otherwise it worked exactly as needed for me.

Comment: Yeah, the `--pgtap-option suffix=.pg` part is only needed if your pgTAP test files end in `.pg`. Mine tend to end in `.sql` these days.